# android xml selector doesn't work

Tags: android, xml

I created a xml file in drawable folder to change my button's color when being pressed, using this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- default -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/purple"
    />

<!-- button focused -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/darkpurple"
    />

<!-- button pressed -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/lightpurple"
    />
```

this is my button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:id="@+id/bt_login"
    android:layout_gravity="top|left|bottom|right"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

I even added color values in color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="gray">#808080</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="background">#4F5680 </color>
    <color name="purple">#04151f </color>
    <color name="darkpurple">#0b3c59 </color>
    <color name="lightpurple">#03141e </color>
    <drawable name="purple">#04151f </drawable>
    <drawable name="darkpurple">#0b3c59 </drawable>
    <drawable name="lightpurple">#03141e </drawable>
</resources>
```

It just doesn't work, instead of being purple like I intended

[image],

it's just white like this

[image: this]

It changes color when I click the button, but to a default gray color, unlike what I expected. What's wrong with my selector?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
android:background="@drawable/button"
```

Instead of this

```
android:drawable="@drawable/button"
```

Comment: I am referring to the button itself, not the selector.

Comment: Ah, it works....mostly. It is purple as default now, after using your method. But it turns to black background when being clicked. The selector doesn't work, it only uses the last entry in my file.

Comment: Try using colors in selector, like this; <item android:...> <color android:color="@color/Purple" /> </item>

Answer (score 2):

In your selector's xml file, instead of using "android:drawable" use "android:color". Also, declare your colors using the "color" tag, not the "drawable" tag.

For reference, here's what mine looks like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:color="@color/search_bar_hint_text_color"
    android:state_focused="false"/>
<item
    android:color="@color/transparent"
    android:state_focused="true"/>
```

Then in my res/values/colors.xml

`<color name="search_bar_hint_text_color">#ffb0b0b0</color>
 <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: It's still the same white background, unlike what I want. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Did you use android:drawable or android:src or android:background in your layout?

Comment: i use android:background